# How do I fix my current openGL error, my cmakelist may be my issue

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glut

I have included the library <GLUT/glut.h> and all my syntax is correct, yet I am receiving this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_glBegin", referenced from:
      triangle(float*, float*, float*) in main.cpp.o
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      displayTriangle() in main.cpp.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glColor3f", referenced from:
      drawTetrahedron(int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glEnable", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glEnd", referenced from:
      triangle(float*, float*, float*) in main.cpp.o
  "_glFlush", referenced from:
      displayTriangle() in main.cpp.o
  "_glLoadIdentity", referenced from:
      displayTriangle() in main.cpp.o
  "_glMatrixMode", referenced from:
      reshapeWindow(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glOrtho", referenced from:
      reshapeWindow(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glVertex3fv", referenced from:
      triangle(float*, float*, float*) in main.cpp.o
  "_glViewport", referenced from:
      reshapeWindow(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutDisplayFunc", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutInitDisplayMode", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutInitWindowSize", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glutPostRedisplay", referenced from:
      reshapeWindow(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glutReshapeFunc", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My cmakefile I feel like is my issue, but I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please provide more details like your relevant section of CMakeLists.txt for getting more info and getting quicker help from community.

Now, coming to the error logs, it seems you are cross-compiling the source files using a arm-based compilers.

The error message "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" looks to me as a linker issue and you should be having the find_package() and linking calls in CMakeLists.txt for OpenGL.

So to start with , you should follow two steps initially and see if it solves your problem:

***1. Make sure the CMake build system is pointing to correct compiler tool chain path (arm compilers in here).***

Refer official website of CMake for same:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html

***2. Make sure you are linking OpenGL***

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(your_executable_name PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(your_executable_name PUBLIC ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})